# Single instance of an object from a file in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is creating 3 socket connections. There needs to be only 1 socket connection. This is probably fundamental javascript, but I am unable to figure out how to access the same instance of an object multiple times.

```
// File: socketConnection.js
// -----------------------------------
let socket = {};
const socketConnection = {};
socketConnection.connect = function() {
    if (!socket.connected) {
        socket = socketio();
    }
};
export default socketConnection;


// File1
// -----------------------------------
import socketConnection from '../../socket/socketConnection';
socketConnection.connect();


// File2
// -----------------------------------
import socketConnection from '../../socket/socketConnection';
socketConnection.connect();


// File3
// -----------------------------------
import socketConnection from '../../socket/socketConnection';
socketConnection.connect();
```

There are good reasons why it needs to be called from 3 separate files. But how can I ensure that there is only one `socket` that is referred to when checking `!socket.connected` ?

Comment: Create some function in _socketConnection.js_ that will return _socketConnection_, then use it to get the instance

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your three calls are all executing so quickly that the socket created in the first call hasn't had a chance to connect yet? You may just be overwriting the socket 3 times. If so, you could change your code to rely instead on whether the socket object has been created instead of its connection status. Something like this:

```
// File: socketConnection.js
// -----------------------------------
let socket;
const socketConnection = {};
socketConnection.connect = function() {
    if (!socket) {
        socket = socketio();
    }
    return socket;
};
export default socketConnection;
```